# Flush Mount USBC Port In Wooden Desktop

Tags: mounting

I have a wooden white laminate desktop for my office desk.  I have a wireless keyboard and mouse.  I'd like to add a usb-c port in my tabletop to be able to charge my keyboard and mouse, and going for a minimalistic and clean aesthetic.

What would be the best way to flush mount [one of these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B8X7R7PT) in my desktop?

Thinking of glueing it to [grommets](https://rubber-grommet.com/white-grommets/) then placing in a drilled hole in the desk.  Not sure the best way to drill this hole.

Once flush mounted, I would connect the bottom side to a power source, then use a cable to charge my keyboard/mouse on the top side.

I only have basic home tools for this project.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. As usual with most things there's no best way to do anything, there are a range of options to pick from and one chooses based on tool availability, effort needed and just personal preference. You need to tell us what tools (if any) you have available to you that you might use for this, as there's no point in someone recommending e.g. a plunge router if you don't own one. (And this wouldn't be the single-use-case to get one.)

Comment: It's not entirely clear but I presume you are intending to mount this vertically? If that's the case then this may be more tricky than it first appears, because there's a very narrow 'shoulder' that the coupler can rest on.

Comment: Now that you've clarified what your desktop is made from we can tell you that this will be harder than you think for a couple of reasons, 1) because of the material your desktop is made from (it's hard to get a clean hole in most white laminate) and 2) because the ideal drill bit for holes of this type is one that is best not used freehand (although the actual hole size needed is an unknown as of yet).

Comment: More of an IT guy here, (with WW as a hobby) inserting an female USB plug into your table in this fashion can be ann issue over time, since it would be extremly diffcult to clean from dust and just dirt in general. Get anything stuck in there and the plug is probably ruined if you have no way of getting it out of the table again.

Answer (score 2):

Your life would be easier if you bought something designed for your application.

No endorsement, but as an example (source Etsy as linked):

[image: USB insert]

[USB insert](https://www.etsy.com/listing/1107008977/usb-c-port-adapter-for-12mm-switch-holes)

(Alternative, more professional looking; google "usb c panel mount", [Panel mount](https://www.coolgear.com/product/usb-panel-mount-extension-1-x-type-c-3-0-and-1-x-usb-3-0-a-male-to-female-cable-ideal-for-rv-car-boat-motorcycle-air-craft-and-desk-installations-3ft))

This would simply require the right sized hole, and the shoulders of the item cover the edge.

If you insist on the original plan, either get geared up with a router template or a bunch of files/rasps. (The router template will be time consuming and the files are unlikely to be perfect.)

Comment: Clicked 2-3 times trying to figure out how you did the "previous/next" image thing before I realized you didn't....

Comment: Inspired by this Im hunting for a couple with ends that looks like this: https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805327287541.html?pdp_npi=2@dis!USD!$1.60!$1.10!!!!!@2101e7f616894384698525012ede1f!12000033372847893!btf&_t=pvid:70a041fb-4999-45bc-b4d9-45057e8c9318&afTraceInfo=1005005513602293__pc__pcBridgePPC__xxxxxx__1689438470&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa

Comment: Those look nice. Two holes with the right sized drill bit, carve out between, and boom! Power! Try eBay if you hate the idea of Aliexpress.

Comment: And @gnicko — sorry I was too lazy to crop well.

Comment: @BeachGeek, the form is, if you found this useful then you upvote it at least and give it the tick if you want to select it as the chosen Answer.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, the requirement is for flush mounting, not surface mounting so the shoulders won't cover the edge of the hole unfortunately. Why a router template when drilled holes will (presumably) do? {And anyway, OP specified they only have "basic home tools" which presumably does not include a router.)

Comment: Agree that the OP said flush, but my experience with clients is that something close to the vision (raised, with shoulders covering the hole) is often acceptable. And given that flush would require real precision to make it nice (ie, tooled up and experienced), it seemed like a near alternative made sense. From the OP's comment link, it looks like a shouldered option works for them.

Comment: I agree, but we're supposed to Answer the Question asked, or do a frame challenge (with explanation) and then in either case to offer one or more alternatives if thought more advisable/more practical. This is why I didn't post an Answer, because I don't think someone with no experience and possibly none of the suitable tools is likely to be able to do what was asked for initially — great accurately is needed first time, with no scope for practice (not even a single trial run unless they're OK with drilling holes on the underside)! Plus the simpler option is still $$-$$$ because Forstners.

Comment: @Graphus — I see where you’re coming from; appreciate the input. I’m sure I can be more explicit with a frame challenge in the future.